# Delay mouse click 0.5 second

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyhook

I am using this code to detect mouse position with pyhook in Windows. What I need is to detect mouse click and add delay before execution - scenario: I click with mouse but this click should be 0.5 second delayed (so click should be executed after 0.5 second). Is this possible somehow?

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom

def onclick(event):
    print event.Position
    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.SubscribeMouseAllButtonsDown(onclick)
hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
hm.UnhookMouse()
```

Comment: What about adding a `time.sleep(0.5)` at the beginning of `onclick`?

Comment: I don't know why but it does not work just simply adding time.sleep

Comment: I got a question : `How do you make it occur in the window you want ?`

Comment: @dsgdfg, I don't know if I understand your question. It should delay click action for 0.5s and then release click action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom
import time
import thread

class _HK :
    def __init__(self):
        self.ev = None
    def run(self,passarg):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        while True :
            if self.ev != None :
                time.sleep(1)
                print self.ev.Position
                self.ev = None

HK = _HK()
s = thread.start_new_thread(HK.run,(None,))


def onclick(event):

    HK.ev = event

    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.SubscribeMouseAllButtonsDown(onclick)
hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
hm.UnhookMouse()
```

> Other definitions are invalid if the application is focused on a
>   process. Initially the process must be resolved by the system. It can
>   then access internal and external components.
>   `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` require for a function or additional process !

I hope it helps(TESTED).