# How to delay mouse click using python?

Tags: python, ui-automation

I am using pynput based listener to detect and record mouse clicks using python.

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        on_release("clicked")
        button = str(button).replace("Button.","")
        inverted_comma = "'"
        button = f"{inverted_comma}{button}{inverted_comma}"
        mouse_values = [x, y, button]
        macro_writer('click',mouse_values)
        
    #image based click
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(1,1)
    time.sleep(2)
    
    x = x-50
    y = y-50
    im3 = pyautogui.screenshot(r"D:\Library\Project\Project\theautomater\src\macro\prett2.png",region=(x,y, 100 , 100))
```

I am able to record the coordinates of the mouse. Problem is I want to record the image/icon where the mouse clicks and as you can see the last line, I can do that but it happens AFTER the click.
This creates the problem that the icon is in "clicked" or "hover" state.

The solution I am thinking of implementing is pausing the click function taking screenshot then clicking.

For this, I need to figure out how to delay the mouse click using python. Can anyone suggest something?

The other question on SO, does not work as intended ([Delay mouse click 0.5 second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347117/delay-mouse-click-0-5-second)), please do not mark as duplicate.

Comment: There's no way to win.  If the button happens to be a dialog OK button, the dialog will be gone by the time you delay.  BTW, why do you have the `inverted_comma` nonsense instead of just writing `f"'{button}'"`?

Comment: If there is a possibility to delay, I can record the intended click coordinates, take screenshot then perform the click myself. That's a win.